# how to Run 'Build installdeps' to install missing prerequisites

Tags: perl, cpan, bioperl

Trying to run a Build.PL file and get following, and not uncommon error message:

```
Checking prerequisites...
  build_requires:
    !  Test::Most is not installed
  recommends:
    *  HTML::TableExtract is not installed
    *  Math::Random is not installed
    *  YAML is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation

Run 'Build installdeps' to install missing prerequisites.
```

however when I run:

```
perl Build installdeps
```

I get:

```
Can't open perl script "Build": No such file or directory
```

anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Build` is a script that is generated after you run `perl Build.PL`. You can execute it without Perl.

Just run:

```
Build installdeps
```

Or (depending on your OS):

```
./Build installdeps
```

Comment: ...and to get the Build script, you need to let Build.PL run to the end rather than cancelling it when it suggests that you install depedencies before proceeding with the installation.